# Creating Dashboard from JSON response in DataDog

Tags: datadog

It's likely I am missing something, but currently to create a dashboard, I first create a metric and then make a dashboard using that metric. The problem is that by default DataDog counts the number of logs, so if I send log XYZ 10 times, it will plot a graph with value 10. Instead what I want is to send log XYZ **once** like this:

```json
{
  value: 10
  label: "some label"
}
```

Based on this information, the dashboard would display plot a graph with value 10.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to achieve what I wanted, by using logs, instead of metrics when creating the dashboard, it gave me the ability to drill down the payload.